# Cannot get Pagination on a list of followers at Instagram API

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get the list of followers via **Instagram API**.
At the process, **Instagram API** does not give me a key of pagination as follows.

I'm at Sandbox mode and creating the app for passing the review of **Instagram API**. Also tried to get data directly via Python library but still does not work.

Could you tell me how to get a key of pagination?

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
access_token = "ACCESS_TOKEN"
client_secret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
followed_by, next = api.user_followed_by()
print next # -> None

# 'pagination' key is empty.
# https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by.json?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
# {
#     "pagination": {},
#     "data": [
#         {
#             "id": "1111111111",
#             "username": "xxxx_xxxx",
#             "full_name": "xxxxxxxxx",
#             "profile_picture": "..."
#         },
#         {
#             "id": "2222222222",
#             "username": "yyyy_yyyy",
#             "full_name": "yyyyyyyyy",
#             "profile_picture": "..."
#         },
#     ],
#     "meta": {"code": 200}
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not get pagination in sandbox mode, you will only get 20 items in response in sandbox mode, once you go live after approval, you will get pagination data to request more users.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

> The behavior of the API when you are in sandbox mode is the same as
>   when your app is live, but comes with the following restrictions:
>
> - Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user